# How to translate text from a script using unity localization?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

I know how to translate the text and so on. But I don't know how to translate text from a script (textMeshPro + value), like this script of mine. I'm using unity's own localization, which is easy for me to use.

Translate the words: Coins and DEATH COUNT + value (data.coin)

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveSlot : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Profile")]
    [SerializeField] private string profileId = "";

    [Header("Content")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject noDataContent;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject hasDataContent;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI CoinText;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI deathCountText;

    [Header("Clear Data Button")]
    [SerializeField] private Button clearButton;

    public bool hasData { get; private set; } = false;

    private Button saveSlotButton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        saveSlotButton = this.GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    public void SetData(GameData data)
    {
        // there's no data for this profileId
        if (data == null)
        {
            hasData = false;
            noDataContent.SetActive(true);
            hasDataContent.SetActive(false);
            clearButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        // there is data for this profileId
        else
        {
            hasData = true;
            noDataContent.SetActive(false);
            hasDataContent.SetActive(true);
            clearButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        
            CoinText.text = "Coins: " + data.coin;
            deathCountText.text = "DEATH COUNT: " + data.deathCount;
        }
    }

    public string GetProfileId()
    {
        return this.profileId;
    }

    public void SetInteractable(bool interactable)
    {
        saveSlotButton.interactable = interactable;
        clearButton.interactable = interactable;
    }
}
```

`

Translate string I already know more or less, but not the TextMeshPro + the value.
How do I have to translate?

Comment: Haven't worked with the localization so far but probably simplest would be to split this .. what you have a clear splitable labels + values so only translate the labels and then have separate TMP_Text for only setting the displayed amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've set-up the Unity [Localization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@1.0/manual/index.html) package, you should already have localisation tables created with your translations.

To fetch your desired translation, you can use the asynchronous `GetLocalizedString(string tableName, string key)` method with the following parameters:

- `tableName`  - Table to search for the original string.
- `key` - The string key taken from the KeyDatabase, that should be used to find the translated text.

For the "Coin**s**" string, you could [extend the parameters](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@0.4/api/UnityEngine.Localization.LocalizedStringDatabase.html) to include the plural type by using `GetLocalizedString(string tableName, string key, int puralValue)`

Alternatively, as of 2020.3+, you could easily localise the TextMeshPro component directly using [Localization Scene Controls](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuideWithVariants.html#localize-strings). Or if you're working on older versions via the [Localize String Event](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html#7-string-localization-create-a-string-table-collection)

Comment: How do you access that function `GetLocalizedString`? I need to dynamically populate the text from within the code so it's not really something like a button with a simple text... Thanks